# How did you find Visual Studio 11 Beta? 

Tags: visual-studio, ide

[Visual Studio 11 Beta version](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us) is released recently. I'm to download and replace my VS2010, while i'm in the middle of some risky projects. How do you find it?
There are many aspects that I wish I can ride of them by putting VS2010 away:

- Single Edmx diagram: It's very important to create separated (splitted) edmx files for large data models.
- Weak garbage collection and memory management: Installing some or many extensions ends to memory problems and exceptions.
- Weak modeling tools: one [unanswered problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433437/how-to-view-name-spaces-in-class-diagram-visual-studio-2010) of mine is an example. Also, I couldn't check my layers references using layer diagram or other kind of available diagrams.

There are many other points, that you and me faced with them.

How's the VS 11 Beta? How did you find it? What are benefits and risks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't replace it. In fact, the user interface is a disaster and was the first thing to make me revolt and uninstall it after ten minutes of use. Now, a user interface doesn't stop me from doing work, sure, but this was so far from an improvement that I won't be touching it until Microsoft brings back some colour into the icons. Even then, the idea that mono-colour glyphs are easier for humans to perceive amongst a sea of other same-coloured glyphs on a background of the same colour is unfounded and unresearched. It seems more that were simply trying to "make it like the other stuff" without even doing any UX testing.

Humans fundamentally evolved colour eyesight because it aids in perceiving our environment. Grass is green, fire is orange, sky is blue, scary monsters are gray and scaly. When users have ten or more years of visual 'muscle' memory behind them, removing colour, let alone shape and form (in the form of object based icons) is disorienting and plain stupid.

No one ever complained that Visual Studio 2010 was too colourful and distracted them from their code, at least not in the way that the developers are complaining about the beta. If anything, it reinforces the structure of the IDE panel and toolbar layout by providing colour, shape and line cues in our peripheral vision.

I could go on, but given the almost universally negative feedback on this issue, I'm not alone in my frustration.

All the features in the world couldn't get me to use a UI like that, especially when I have a user interface as nice as Visual Studio 2010's. I had trouble separating the IDE into panels and objects. Which gray rectangle with gray shapes is the solution explorer. Which gray rectangle with gray shapes is the toolbox?

Comment: Good points Nick, and I hope this nightmare end in next release.

Comment: I find that you need a well calibered monitor. If your grays arent coming out well on your screen, it will look horible. But with a nice screen, it really looks nice to me. Sure, it isnt as contrasted as VS 2010, but it didnt change radically (still is an IDE) so I could find quite easily what I wanted, even by choosing not to import my settings from VS2010

Answer (score 2):

Well, visually, it is quite different. Really heavily inspired by WP7, and the expression blend suite. 
I find it quite appealing visually speaking. It also seems more user friendly while installed out of the box (you can however import settings from your current VS installation, which I chose not to do)

You get some pack of additionnal tools, and seem easier to access (at lest IMO).

Concerning extensions, we will have to wait and see, but most of the extensions I use are quite good, and dont crash inexpectedly, so I believe the extension developper is more at fault than Visual Studio itself :).

You should simply try it out to see, because you can install side by side with your current VS install, it should not interfer

Comment: I think VS should monitor on memory usage and garbage collection of extensions.
Extensions aside, how does it treat with v2010 projects on TFS? Am I forced to convert the project and ask other team members to do so?

Comment: Concerning the TFS, i dont know, I pulled my project from the TFS, then converted it, but I never updated the TFS afterwards. I mainly tested on personnal stuff, which is on a SVN, so I cant tell you.

But conversion process doesnt look nearly as heavy as the conversion from VS 2008 to VS 2010 but that could be du to my computer.

Comment: Reza - cant you just copy teh .sln file and then rename to -> projectName-vs2011.sln ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find Visual Studio 11 Beta [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us).

I haven't used it to be honest, although your question implies you're going to replace VS2010 with the new Beta version - that's not a good idea! You should be able to download and install it alongside Visual Studio 11 until it's released properly.

Comment: Sure, I just want to have an overview of new VS.